# Flexslider bottom orientated images

Tags: image, height, flexslider

I get a problem with images of a different height by using the Flexslider plugin.

I'm trying to orientate the **img-tags** in the class **img_block** at the bottom of the **img_block div**, so that all are vertical aligned at the bottom. 
My idea of setting the **`div`** `position: relative` and the img-tag `position: absolute, bottom: 0` didn't work well with Flexslider.

Does anyone have a solution, that is working well and responsively with the plugin?